# Jquery append - appending double?

Tags: jquery, append

Why is this code appending the object twice for each element?

```
$('input[data-type="answer"]').each(function (index, input) {
    var name = $(input).attr('name');
    var value = $(input).val();
    $("#QuizQuestion").append('<div id="QuizQuestionHeadline"></div><div class="control-group"><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="input-fluid" value="' + value + '" />' + value + '</label></div>');
});
```

Thanks!

---

Realized I published wrong code, here it is:

Jquery to create the answers:

```
var newAnswerAlt = "appendAnswerAltRadio" + i++;
    $("<div><div class='controls'><input type='text' class='answerAltRadiobtn' data-type='answer' class='input-fluid' name='txtAnswer"+ n++ +"'> <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id='QuizCheckbox"+ c++ +"'> Correct Answer</label></div></div>").attr({id: newAnswerAlt, class: ''}).prependTo(".NewQuizAnswersGroup").hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

Jquery to get the attributes from the created answers and append them to another element:

```
    $('input[data-type="answer"]').each(function(index, input){
        var name = $(input).attr('name');
        var value = $(input).val();     
        var question = "txtQuestion1";      
        $("#QuizQuestion").append('<div id="QuizQuestionHeadline"></div><div class="control-group"><label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="input-fluid" name="' + question + '" value="'+value+'" />'+value+'</label></div>');          
        });

    var NewQuizQuestion = $("#NewQuizQuestion").val();
    $("#QuizQuestionHeadline").append("<legend>"+NewQuizQuestion+"</legend>");  

     $('input[data-type="UserDetails"]').each(function(index, input){
    var name = $(input).attr('name');
    var label = $("label[for='"+name+"']").text()
    var value = $(input).is(":checked");
    if($(input).is(":checked")){
        $("#formAlts").append('<div id="formHeader"></div><div class="control-group"><label>'+label+'</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" class="input-fluid" name="' + name + '" /></div></div>');
    }
    });

    var formHeader = "Fill out form";
    $("#formHeader").append("<legend>"+formHeader+"</legend>");

    var terms = "Accept Terms & Conditions";
    $("#terms").append("<div class='control-group'><label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='txtTerms'>"+terms+"</label></div>");
```

The second call for "'input[data-type="UserDetails"]'" works fine but not for "'input[data-type="answer"]'".

Can't really understand it!

Comment: Are you sure that the `each()` loop is not getting called twice?

Comment: Just wondering, how many answers per question are there?

Comment: It should be possible to create new answers dynamically, and after that it is being requested by the above code to use them. But for some reason it doubles every answer with a blank input-field (?) And it doesn't seem the loop is called twice

Comment: Is it possible to see more code. When this is called or executed? What your HTML looks like?

Comment: Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with duplicate IDs (HTML IDs must be unique): every time you do the `append`, you create another element with ID "QuizQuestionHeadline". That wouldn't cause the double append, mind you, but I suspect it points to a larger issue within your page. If the ID "QuizQuestion" is duplicated, the jQuery selector engine would find the first instance and make all of the appends to that element alone, rather than to subsequent questions. Without more code/HTML this is just speculative, however.

Comment: Okey, I've tried to look for dublicate IDs but cannot find any, and there is only one ID called "QuizQuestion". I added some code if it makes is more clear! Or if there is something else in my code that makes the problem